# implementation of AutoSuggestion feature of apps like alibaba using elastic search

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement "autosuggestion" feature in my application where when user type a set of letters she should be able to view a list of suggestions for the given input , i would like to have my feature working as similar to how Alibaba or similar sites work .

I am using Elastic search  and java.Can any one help me or give any suggestions on how to implement this functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately this is **not** a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Answer (score 0):

suggestins in elastic search can be implemented using 1)prefix match 2)completion suggesters 3)Edge NGrams.

in this approach i choose "Ngrams analyzer" for auto suggestion ,  start by defining a nGram filter and then link the filter to custom analyzer and apply analyzer to fields which we choose to provide suggestions.

```
"settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
```

once we have mapping set , we can assign the analyzer(nGram_analyzer) to fileds which take part of suggestions.
Next step would be to write a query to extartc suggestions , that would be as follows.

```
     "query": {
          "match": {
             "_all": {
                "query": "gates",
                "operator": "and"(optional , needed when we have multiple words or a senetence)
             }
          }

   }
```

The below material would help to understand in depth about ngram tokenizer 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

PS :  each approach listed above will have its own advantages and backdrops.